# Why is Eclipse not showing runClient when starting the mod?

Tags: minecraft-forge

It's just an empty mod but it has all the required files. When I first clicked run it said to choose a but runClient wasn't there, it is in the files and I checked that and ran the command to make all the needed files but it still didn't show up when I clicked run and change configuration. I attached some screenshots on what it looks like and what my mod folder looks like. btw I open the folder that has all my mods and not the one that has the specific mod I need to launch, maybe that's the problem but when I open the folder of the mod I'm making right now the folder is empty. [image: What I see when I click run configuration][image: What I see when I try to change the configuration]

Comment: I feel dumb now; just needed to refresh my Gradle project for my Run Configs to display. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried running the command `genEclipseRuns`?
If not, then  the run configurations `runClient`, `runServer` and `runData` will not appear.
When you click on your project folder, in the tab "Gradle Tasks", the command `genEclipseRuns` will appear. Double click it and your problem should be solved.

If you have done it already,
then click on File menu -> Import -> Run Configurations -> Select your project and select all three commands(runClient, runServer and runData).
That's it :).